# How to access the original object when unpacking properties from objects passed as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

consider I've below code -

```js
const user = {
  id: 42,
  username: "usrname",
  info: {
    fullName: "John",
    age: 15,
  },
};

function foo({ username: usrnam, info: { age } }) {
  return `${usrnam} ${age} `;
}

console.log(foo(user));
```

Here I'm unpacking properties username, info, age etc in the function `foo` call. I would like to know if it is possible to have access to user object while unpacking?

I need to set some property in user object based on age in the `foo` function.

Thanks in advance.